# How to customize CSS depending on (tinier) window size?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I've seen that there is a different css called depending on how large the screen is.

Example normal size:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVR4k.png]

Note the red bar does not have any margin-bottom and the text is custom css
(provided in an extra css file, not bootstrap.css)

Example tiny size:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/oReZCRW.png]

Note that the css I have added is basically gone.

How can I fix this?
I thought it was something with

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
```

But after adding this in the extra css file it doesn't get fixed.

This is the CSS I used:

```
#The red bar
.top .alert {
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#The text css
.very-big {
color: #20F587;
font-size: 115px;
text-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
font-weight: bold;
}
.title-very-big {
color: #20F587;
font-size: 75px;
text-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
font-weight: bold;
}
.p-very-big {
color: #20F587;
font-size: 15px;
text-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: It would probably be easier to answer you if you could show us your custom css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a url to inspect it would be helpful.

that said:

anything in `@media (max-width: 767px)` will *not* appear in the bigger version.

`max-width` styles won't appear on screens bigger than the setting (in your case `767px`), and `min-width` styles won't appear until the screen is at least as big as the setting. so if the desired margin and text styles are only working at a large size, chances are it is because they are in a `min-width` query somewhere, not a `max-width`.

sidenote: if possible, it is better (and makes things so much easier) to remove unwanted styles instead of trying to override styles.

**edit:**
i found your site at http://mrblackdragonfly.com/404/

the `.top .alert` has a `margin-bottom:0px;`, but it is inside a `(min-width: 768px)` query. move it out of there and the margin problem should go away.

the same goes for your text style.

Comment: It is totally unique css and does not override anything.
I'm not very good with @media too, could you maybe give a beginner answer? O, and this is the url: http://mrblackdragonfly.com/404/

Comment: remove lines 49 and 52 of style.css

Comment: think of media queries like a body class or something. for example: `body.min767 p { font-size: 12px }` would override `p { font-size: 16px }`

Comment: A I see! I missed a curly bracket! Thank you really much for helping me out!